# draw grayscale picture from hex data

Tags: c#, .net

I have hex data and I want to convert it to 200x200 pixel grayscale picture, but I can't find a way to do it.

Can anyone please show me a way or give me a resource to solve this problem??

Comment: please explain what you're trying to do a bit better. Should the image display a given piece text in a chosen font/fontsize?

Comment: how ascii data is related to pixels color? how is your data?

Comment: sorry I mistaken ascii with hex,,my task on school actually ask me to make a grayscale pic from hex data...Can you please help me,, I really confuse,,

Comment: this is my contact ecaiseng@yahoo.com,,I really appreciate your help...

Comment: You should clarify which input format you're using (e.g. is it a string, a byte array or just a memory address? You could as well just post your actual task's text or the given data/values.

Comment: It doesn't help SO if you take the question elsewhere, ecaiseng.

Comment: @mario : my first task is to make a grayscale image from hex input,,I really don't have any idea how to do that so I just search from web site & try anything they suggest,,

Comment: @ mario : OK please wait I'll post my actual data/value the task given

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what you have written (too few) you could create `Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(200,200)`.
Then you could use `bmp.SetPixel(x,y,color)` according to your text data.

**UPDATE**:
Assuming a lot of things:

- you have a **hexstr** containing hex data representing your bmp
- **hexstr** is made of two chars groups (hex data)
- every hex data group is 2 or 6 chars long (2 chars if hex val is already a greyscale val, 6 chars if you have a RGB value to convert to grayscale)

**SECOND UPDATE**:
Your file contanins 16x2450=39200 pixel, so your image cannot be 200x200. I assume it's 200x192.
This code works, even if I don't understand what image represents...

You can try this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    string hexstr = FileToHexStr(path_to_file);
    pictureBox1.Image = ConvertToBmp(hexstr, 200, 196, true);
}

private string FileToHexStr(string filename)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    string[] f = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
    foreach (string s in f) sb.Append(s.Trim().Replace(" ", ""));
    return sb.ToString();
}

private byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                     .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                     .Select(x => System.Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                     .ToArray();
}

private Bitmap ConvertToBmp(string hexstr, int width, int height, bool isGrayScaleString)
{
    /// If hexstr is a color bitmap I assume that a single pixel
    /// must be 3 values long (one for R, one for G, one for B);
    /// if not, then every hex value is a pixel
    int bpp = isGrayScaleString ? 1 : 3;
    byte[] hexarr = StringToByteArray(hexstr);
    // Check if string is correct
    if (hexarr.Length != (width * height * bpp)) return null;

    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < hexarr.Length; i +=  bpp)
    {
        int luma = (int)(isGrayScaleString ?
            hexarr[index] :
            // Formula to convert from RGB to Grayscale
            // <see>http://www.bobpowell.net/grayscale.htm</see>
            0.3 * hexarr[i] + 0.59 * hexarr[i + 1] + 0.11 * hexarr[i + 2]);
        Color c = Color.FromArgb(luma, luma, luma);
        bmp.SetPixel(index % width, index / width, c);
        index++;
    }
    return bmp;
}
```

Comment: @marco : Sorry internet connection is pretty bad here,,I try your code (it run smoothly) and do some experiment with the code I found on website earlier..But I can not make it into a [form design](http://www.mediafire.com/?vby4p2dm3qddk11) I plan to use,,

Comment: @marco : should I use picturebox method??and when I use action button to convert my hex data to image the code show error build...This is code I try based on your code...

Comment: @ marco : It show error in **buttonconvert_Click** method & **buttonconvert** in line Bitmap bmp = buttonconvert(hexstr, 200, 200, isGrayScale)...

Comment: Oh yeah this is [hex data](http://www.mediafire.com/?c03oxpzak93dc58) I need to convert to image...

Comment: @ecaiseng: a lot of things. First, new code is posted and it works. Second: you are not a good student, you're neither good to write some code by yourself nor understand my code... so, for God's sake: **study**, study a lot. Your homeworks cannot always be done from someone else. Accept my answer as the good one and study my code, believe me!!!

Comment: @marco : yes I will study a lot from now on,,I will study so I can make some usefull code someday...

Comment: @marco : I really need to say thank you to you,,thanks for help me to study...I really appreciate your effort to help me,,

Comment: @ecaiseng: I'm a father and if my children will do like you're doing, well I'll get really angry. You should first study, then try, try, try, try and try again improving your knowledge and at the end (**ONLY** at the end) ask someone's help... OK, I've helped you even if, perhaps, I shouldn't have to... but now study my code and **understand** what it's doing. Consider it's not optimized: if so it could have been too difficult for you, really... Accept this answer and study :)

Comment: @marco : how should I close this post??I'm a newbie...I search everywhere but I can't find a function to close this forum/post,,

Comment: @marco : Yeah I will study and improve your code as far as I can... I consider you as my teacher since you show me how to make a code... And I believe you will teach your children as well as you guide me here..thanks a lot

Comment: @marco : Oh by the way,,I think I begin to understand the flow of your code...thanks

Comment: @ecaiseng: I hope I can teach my children as I'm teaching you :) Good luck for your future, really!! When you have decided which answer best solves your problem you can mark the answer as accepted. All you have to do is click the outline of the tick next to the answer. Once selected it will go green. See this [FAQ article](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for further information.

Comment: @ecaiseng: consider that my conversion method is good both for greyscale bitmaps and coloured ones (represented by groups of hex data). If the string is for greyscale bmp, I take current value as color, while for colour bmp I take 3 values (one for red, one for green and one for blue) and convert them in a greyscale color using one possible algorithm (it's just one I know it's quite good).

Comment: @marco : OK thanks I hope you will help me again when I have another problem,,

Comment: @ecaiseng: if you study, I'll be glad to help you again :)

Comment: @ecaiseng: let me know if you are able to let my code works for what you need and the mark you get on the homework :)